# What is efficient way to lock threads from simultaneous ONLY per file, not just write to any file operation?

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider trivial scenario. We have some game where each player is represented by a thread. Our server is fragile and frequently dies due to God action therefore we need to persist state of game sessions in case the of server failure. We cannot use database just because we love to have our life over-complicated.

So I try to be somewhat original in this exercise:

- Each new game session is saved in a file under randomly generated
  UUID file name.
- Game session modification(users actions) are    persisted in a file
  corresponding to a game session.
- 10 Games with 20 users = 10 files with random UUID generated names

**Now the question:**
It is very easy to synchronise write on global context i.e. only one thread can write/overwrite the file. This means that while the state of 1st out 10 game is persisted other 9 game sessions' threads(players) wait to persist their own states.

**How do I ensure that only same game-session threads block each other from writing to the same file, but 2 threads corresponding to different game sessions can write simultaneously to two files?**

FileLock as I've done investigation is for inter-process locking - not inter-thread so no help here.

Only obvious solution seems to be synchronising on UUID strings, such that when thread creates/reads/writes on the same UUID string I obtain the lock.

What are the risks of such approach? If I guarantee that Strings are very unique to these operations: "game_session_identifier_" + UUID should work and not lock something else accidentally. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronise on a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) for each file

```
private Map<String, Semaphore> semaphores = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

Then in your code:

```
Semaphore semaphore = semaphores.computeIfAbsent(filename, () -> new Semaphore(1, true));
semaphore.acquireUninterruptibly();
// write to file
semaphore.release();
```

You'll have to put some more code around this and finally blocks to ensure you don't get into a blocked state, but this is the essence of the approach.

Comment: Why do you suggest Semaphore and not Lock? Or you derived the solution from my 10 games - 20 users requirement? If I have unlimited number of users I can just use same concept but with ReentrantLock? Also could you please explain if plain string approach will work - I am still gonna do concurrent map, but would like to know why all answers here did not comment on plain string synchronization. Thanks for help!

Comment: @Aubergine you can't synchronise on a plain string unless you intern it to ensure you get the *same* string object, not just the same String value like `.equals()`, but like `==`. Use whatever synchronization object you want; idea of a concurrent map to get them is the key

Answer (score 0):

You can use a semaphore from java.util.concurrent package. Each Game has its own semaphore for write action (for example), so when one thread starts to write smth to file, he acquires the semaphore, and another thread in this Game will wait until the first one will finish.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems to be correct but a simplified version of your solution would be to have a file to lock map.

```
Map<Path, Lock> locks = ... a lock per file;

void writeData(path Path, byte[]data){
 Lock lock = Objects.requireNonNull(locks.get(path));
 try{
   lock.lock();
   //write data
 }finally{
   lock.unlock();
 }

}
```